# Issue no tty present and no askpass program specified on my new Mac M1 with dockware

Tags: docker, docker-compose, shopware6

I'm facing issue with my new Mac wit M1 Chip.
I use the same config as on my old mac where it worked:

```
version: '3'

services:
  shop:
    container_name: shop
    image: dockware/dev:latest
    ports:
      - "22:22"     # ssh
      - "80:80"     # apache2
      - "443:443"   # apache2 https
      - "8888:8888" # watch admin
      - "9998:9998" # watch storefront proxy
      - "9999:9999" # watch storefront
      - "3306:3306" # mysql port
    volumes:
      - "db_volume:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "shop_volume:/var/www/html"
    networks:
      - web
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=shopware
      - MYSQL_PWD=secret
      - XDEBUG_ENABLED=0

  rediscache:
    image: redis:6.0
    container_name: redis
    networks:
      - web

volumes:
  db_volume:
    driver: local
  shop_volume:
    driver: local

## ***********************************************************************
##  NETWORKS
## ***********************************************************************
networks:
  web:
    external: false
```

The error i get is :

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I already pruned image and containers but still get this error.

On my research, i found solutions where i need to edit sudoer file or set permission, but it's docker image, so I can not use those solutions.

Anyone an idea why and how to solve that?

Comment: Nothing in that Compose file obviously calls `sudo`; it'd be pretty unusual for anything inside a container to run it.  Do you have a [mcve] that shows how that command is being invoked?

Comment: So the error is inside the container logs. Docker just tells me exited on entrypoint.sh

Comment: I also face the same issue in a Mac with M2. Till now no solution found.

Answer (score 0):

For same problem in my case macOS with M2, I fixed it passing a user param with value `root` or `0`.
For example

```bash
docker run -p 80:80 -u root --name shopwarelocal dockware/dev:latest

or

docker run -p 80:80 -u 0 --name shopwarelocal dockware/dev:latest
```

For Docker compose

```yaml
....
services:
  shopware:
    user: 'root'
    container_name: shopware
    image: dockware/dev:6.5.0.0
....
```

Answer (score -1):

Please open a shell in the container (`docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash`) and execute the entrypoint script manually.

You should see that prompt when running it manually.

Probably the setup or so is trying to ask for something interactively, which fails if there is no TTY.